Illegal Invocation when trying to read serial ports in Ubuntu
Hi on my windows environment npm serialport works great. Anyone ever have issues with Illegal invocation when trying to read COM port data in Linux? Code looks OK and as i mentioned it works great on Windows. Permissions in linux OK for serial port also as i can read the data OK in cutecom. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

"Code looks OK" - We can't judge about that as you haven't posted any code. Please have a look at how to create a [mre]

if (this.balance1Type == "Dini Argeo") {
this.parser.on("data", (data) => {
const reading = data.toString("utf-8").trim();
const readingChanged = reading.replace(" ", "").split(",");
const readingVal = readingChanged[2]; // Third element
const weightUnit = readingChanged[3]; // Fourth element
this.scaleValue = readingVal; // Update scaleValue with the received data
this.scaleUnit = weightUnit;
});

Please edit the question and add all details inside the question. The comment section is not the place to share code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Apologies here is link
https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/discussions/2815
I put it on here also. get same result on macOS
